# Safari removing Sec-WebSocket-Extensions header from response

Tags: websocket, safari, compression, mobile-safari

I'm trying to add a web socket extension in Node that behaves similar to permessage-deflate. My issue is everything works up until the point node sends back it's handshake with the Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame. The request from Safari includes this, but if I include it in the response to try and tell Safari to go ahead and use compression, it never shows up as a header in the Network tab. I have confirmed via Wireshark that we are sending it in the response but I can't figure out why safari is removing it. I've looked everywhere possible but no one seems to have this issue.

I have also tried using:

```
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame; server_no_context_takover

Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame; no_context_takover

Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame; client_no_context_takeover

Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame; server_no_context_takeover; client_no_context_takeover
```

And anytime I use any of the no context takeovers Safari removes everything from the response headers.

Comment: What's with the extra details? Why do you think Safari would support them? Is it in the `x-webkit-deflate-frame` specs?

Comment: @Myst, I think you're confused. The extras details were me trying other things besides just responding with `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame` to see if those would make it work.

Comment: I actually had same issue when developing my own web socket server so provided an answer. Hope it's useful

Comment: So did you manage to get around this one?

Answer (score 0):

If you reply with "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame" and actually your WebSocket server supports compression, then it should work. I just tested this myself.

As for why Safari is hiding your response header, I have no idea. Again, tested and checked with Wireshark - the compression works. When I send 1000 bytes (char 'A' repeated 1000 times), the packet is around 1064 bytes, when I enable compression on server, the packet is around 76 bytes.

Comment: By the way, when I created first version of my WebSocket server a year or so ago, as far as I remember, I could see the response "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions" header. Maybe it is something to do with a newer version of Safari?